# Creating a site-specific SmokeDetector chat room

Tags: support, chat, spam, askubuntu, chatbot

I am a regular user of Ask Ubuntu. Simply, how can I make a chat room that only has SmokeDetector posting about **Ask Ubuntu** and Ask Ubuntu only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen you already created [a gallery chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62566/smokedetector-ask-ubuntu) for this purpose and added SmokeDetector to it. In theory, that means you can drop by in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and ask one of the [administrators or developers](https://charcoal-se.org/people) to add this room to the list of rooms Smokey posts in. There are other rooms in the network for exactly this purpose, like [The Spam Blot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56223/the-spam-blot) on Graphic Design. It's a very simple change in SmokeDetector's codebase; in fact, if you have a GitHub account and know a little bit of Python, you can make the [change yourself](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/ws.py#L163) (it needs to be approved by one of the developers/admins though).

However, I have two questions (feel free to answer them here in the comments, but it's probably better if you head over to Charcoal HQ to discuss):

1. SmokeDetector posts already in the [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877). Why do you need an extra chatroom for this?
2. What's the purpose of making the room a gallery room instead of a public one?

Comment: Both for the same reason - so I don't get excess messages and can look back on there and **only** see SmokeDetector.

Comment: Also I just looked at the code. It shouldn't be too hard to make a pull request! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I agree with ubashu. I checked the Charcoal room 2 days before and spend some time there. It'll be good if there is a room in which only Smokey can add message. I am thinking of doing the same. but one question, will it make any impact on the api call limit?

Comment: @SagarV for the SE API it doesn't matter. Chat itself *is* rate limited, but I don't know if that's a global limit or room-based.

Comment: Can I filter it to send message reg- a specific site. ie stackoverflow?

Comment: @SagarV for SO it might be different, because it's a separate chat server. I have to check once I'm not on mobile anymore. Filtering is automatic for special rooms.

Comment: the room is not private, it's a gallery chat room. That's a rather different thing.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, corrected.